# Is there any way to apply type casting in Queryable sql using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, sql, casting, .net-core, expression

How can I use type casting in Queryable collection which contains a Sql query in .net core. My expression is following which is returning just string value right now but I want to return value according to the datatype passed to it.

I have tried [Expression.Convert type for Expression.Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941420/expression-convert-type-for-expression-property) but this is not supported in Sql.

Following is my expression where TSource is source which contains the property containing string value and TDataType is datatype to be converted into.

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TDataType>> CreateMapFromExpression<TSource, TDataType>(string fieldName, TypeCode dataType)
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));

    var collectionParameter = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "CustomFieldValues");
    var childType = collectionParameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var propertyParameter = Expression.Parameter(childType, childType.Name);

    var left = Expression.Property(propertyParameter, "Name");
    var right = Expression.Constant(fieldName);

    var innerLambda = Expression.Equal(left, right);

    var innerFunction = Expression.Lambda(innerLambda, propertyParameter);

    var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "FirstOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).FirstOrDefault().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(CustomFieldValue));

    var outerLambda = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Property(parameterExpression, collectionParameter.Member as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo), innerFunction);
    var propertyGetter = Expression.Property(outerLambda, "Value");            

    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDataType>>(propertyGetter, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This can't be done because the C# rules for converting things aren't the same as the SQL rules for converting things (and those in turn depend on your provider). The closest thing providers get to is stuff like `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` for a specific subset of conversions. The best you could do here is execute the query, then convert the results afterwards as you get them. To do this generically you'd need to generate more code, outside the expression tree.

Comment: Can't we use Expression.Convert or something?

Comment: No, almost no provider would support that because it's not meaningful. `Expression.Convert` is the equivalent of a C# cast, but most conversions of this nature can't be expressed through casts. For example, `(string) 5` is not valid, even though reading an `INT` column as a `string` is perfectly reasonable. You can use `Expression.Convert` outside this particular expression tree, after the provider is done querying and you can switch to LINQ to Objects with `.AsEnumerable()` -- but even then it only really makes sense for the kind of "cast" where you actually already know the cast will work.

Comment: But I have thousands of records if I will not apply type casting in query itself then there will be no use of IQueryable

Comment: It seems quite likely that whatever it is you're trying to accomplish either has already been done somewhere, somehow (things like dynamic LINQ and Automapper spring to mind, also EF and code generation) or there's an easier solution that requires that you take a step back and reevaluate your strategy. From the code in your question I can't tell what you're actually trying to achieve on a higher level, but it feels like your troubles with casting are due to an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Actually I am using Automapper to map some dynamic fields which are having different datatypes on runtime. But for the time being all are mapped to string fields because I am not able to add type conversion using automapper or expression. This is the thing I want to achieve either using Autopmapper or Expression

var map2 = cfg.CreateMap<CustomerGridViewModel, CustomerGridViewModelResult>();
map2.ForMember(fieldName, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.CustomFieldValues.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == fieldName).Value));

Comment: In code mentioned in above comment, value is coming as string but the fieldName present in Destination is of different datatype

Comment: I have done it by using scalar function in sql. I have explained in my comments in my other question as following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684233/how-to-call-sql-scalar-function-in-expression-tree-of-linq-queryable?noredirect=1#comment98257157_55684233