# How to call sql scalar function in Expression tree of linq queryable?

Tags: c#, linq, function, lambda, expression

I am creating lambda expression for Iqueryable to get value from a collection but I want to convert that value to other datatype like int or decimal. So as I cannot use c# casting with Iqueryable so I have created user defined scalar function in sql and trying to access that in expression but it throws exception that the 'methodname' cannot be converted to sql expression.

```
public class Context
{

[DbFunction("dbo", "ConvertToDouble")]
        public int? ConvertToDouble(string value)
        {
            var sql = $"set @result = dbo.[ConvertToDouble]('{value}')";
            var output = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = @"result", DbType = DbType.Int32, Size = 16, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var result = Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, output);
            return output.Value as int?;
        }
}


private static Expression<Func<TSource, TDataType>> CreateLamdaExpression<TSource, TDataType>(string fieldName)
        {
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));

            var collectionParameter = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "CustomFieldValues");
            var childType = collectionParameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var propertyParameter = Expression.Parameter(childType, childType.Name);

            var left = Expression.Property(propertyParameter, "Name");
            var right = Expression.Constant(fieldName);

            var innerLambda = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            var innerFunction = Expression.Lambda(innerLambda, propertyParameter);

            var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "FirstOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).FirstOrDefault().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(CustomFieldValue));

            var outerLambda = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Property(parameterExpression, collectionParameter.Member as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo), innerFunction);
            var propertyGetter = Expression.Property(outerLambda, "Value");

            if (typeof(TDataType) != typeof(object))
            {
               /var changeTypeCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(Context), Context.GetType().GetMethod("ConvertToDouble", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance),
                                                            propertyGetter
                                                               );

                Expression convert = Expression.Convert(changeTypeCall,
                                                        typeof(TDataType));

                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDataType>>(convert, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
            }

            var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDataType>>(propertyGetter, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression });
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Does `Context` inherit from `DbContext` in your actual code?

Comment: A lot of work...why not just create a specialized stored procedure which returns your model as you like it or with different permutations of this value within its model?

Comment: Are you using EF or LINQ to SQL? If EF, what version? Have you defined your function to EF as a SQL function?

Comment: I am able to achieve this by using EntityFramework.Functions in following way:

 [ComposableScalarValuedFunction("fn_ConvertToBool", Schema = dbo)]
        public bool? fn_ConvertToBool(
  [Parameter(DbType = "nvarchar")] string value) =>
      Function.CallNotSupported<bool?>();